# Magento2 add to Wishlist then error is showing this : Item (Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item\Interceptor) with the same ID "7" already exists

Tags: wishlist, addtowishlist, multiplewishlist

Frontend customer dashboard adds to Wishlist issue :

Magento2 add Wishlist then an error is showing this: Exception #0 (Exception): Item (Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item\Interceptor) with the same ID "7" already exists.

so give me the solution

Comment: My first check would be to see if there is any module that joins table when loading wishlist collection that results in doubling wishlist items rows in the sql query. You can start by disabling all 3rd modules and enabling them one by one to see which one is causing problem.

Comment: Ok Sure I will check. thank you so much. and let me know

Comment: not solution any get. so please help me more in details